# Variables not showing correct value in python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have the following code that works fine in python 3 but for some reason in python 2 the variables Count and EmptyLine are always 0.  However, inside the loop the variables update without a problem.  I don't know python 2 all that well and the production server is unfortunately running on python 2.  What am I missing?  I'm guessing it has something to do with variable scope but not entirely sure.

```
 def ParseFile(self,ConfigFile):

    EmptyLine       = 0
    Count           = 0

    with open( ConfigFile ,'r') as fp:

        
        AllLines     = fp.readlines()

        for line in AllLines:
            if line == '\n' and EmptyLine == 0 and Count > 5:
                    EmptyLine = Count
   


            Count   = Count + 1
            x       = re.search("Scale', true", line)
            if x:
                return

    print(Count)
```

Comment: In python2, print is a statement and not a function.

Comment: You are defining `EmptyLine` and `Count` inside the function, and they will go away once the function finishes.  The `print` should work, but I don't see how either variable would exist outside the function in either Python 2 or Python 3.

Comment: They don't need to exist outside the function.  But they do need to work outside the loop